# How can I force bind particular process in Windows to use specific network interface and to route all its traffic via this interface?

Tags: windows, routing

I need to allow users inside my lan to use BitTorrent clients, but I need to route **all** BitTorrent (and **only** BitTorrent) traffic via Bulletproof VPN. In other words, I need to prevent advertising my router's WAN address as a BitTorrent peer address.

Well, I can establish VPN connection on every Windows PC (via Bulletproof VPN) and it seems I can bind every BitTorrent client to the VPN interface using [forcebindip](https://r1ch.net/projects/forcebindip), but how can I instruct Windows to use different gateway for the VPN interface/address? Is there something like PBR in Linux?

Edit: Maybe I'm wrong, but basic routing is the same in Windows and Linux – it is destination-based. All IP packets regardless of source address will be routed to the same gateway. But If I want to send packets to the same destination using different gateways, I need some kind of policy-based routing (in this case – source-based routing)

Comment: If you've bound the client to the interface then you've already succeeded.

Comment: Please clarify. For instance, I have 2 interfaces: lan0 (192.168.100/24) and lan1 (10.10.100/24) and default gateway 192.168.100.1. Process1 bound to lan1. Where will its packets be routed? It seems to me that to 192.168.100.1. But I need them to be routed to 10.10.100.1. How it can be done?